# Best way to add a printer to a computer

Tags: windows-10, networking, printer, home-networking, network-printer

We have an HP desk jet (HP DeskJet Ink Advantage 3835 All-in-One Printer) , and it is connected using wifi on our home router/modem network. However, I'm not sure if the computers of the other people using the same printer, in my house, are virus free.

1. Is it possible for a computer that is connected in the home network and adds the printer using the automated process of windows 10 (when you go to Printers and scanners then Add a printer or scanner and then when it shows it click add, I think it mentions it as web service) to get infected with a virus? I choose to not share, but I don't know how it works.
2. I was wondering what's the safest way for someone to add it on their computer without risking getting a virus?

Using WSD or TCP/IP (through control panel - it has a fixed IP) port of the printer or hp network discovery?

Comment: Windows print drivers are signed.  You have little to worry about.  Is it *possible*.. sure.  It is *possible*.. everything is *possible* but great lengths have been taken taken to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Follow the printer instructions on how to add it and its driver.

Comment: Have them connect to the printer, don't share it from your PC.  Don't worry.